# app crashes upon parsing int from empty EditText

Tags: java, android

I make an app name higher or lower number. Everything works fine except 
when i add a number. If the edit text field is empty and i do not enter any numeric value in number edittext view then i press button the app crashes.

```
public void guessIt (View view) {
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    /* actually guessIt is the function of the button which will
    executed upon clicking to the button till now we are
    making another method which does not exist before
    in this method we will do the following
     */
    int guessItInt = Integer.parseInt (editText1.getText().toString());
    /* this int guessItInt is a code to convert string to int

     */
    if(guessItInt > randomNumber) {
       makeToast("Lower");
    } else if (guessItInt < randomNumber){
      makeToast("Higher");
    } else {
      makeToast("You win");
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) +1;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) +1;
    //This nadomnumber is a formula to generate random number
    //but we will still need another method to convert string to int
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get?  it's usually best to provide all the code.  Where is randomNumber defined?  All that being said, you need to validate your inputs.  The issue is likely here: `editText1.getText().toString()`... if it's an empty string or not a number, it will crash your app.  You should check what the user has given you, and maybe wrap it in a try/catch block.

Comment: hi is there any solution ?

Comment: Looks like there are several suggestions on this page.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between an empty content in the edit field and non-empty content (in best case you allow digits only here).

If the edit field is empty and the button pressed in your code the line

```
int guessItInt = Integer.parseInt (editText1.getText().toString());
```

is executed. With `editText1.getText()` returning  an empty `String`, the `Integer.parseInt` method will throw a `NumberFormatException`. I assume that this is not handled in your code and hence causes the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt (editText1.getText().toString());
```

If the editText1 field is empty, then you will be passing an empty String to parseInt.  This will cause an exception, since the string does not contain a representation of a parsable integer. You should put this line inside a try-catch block and handle the situation where the text does not represent an integer.

Comment: Hi but can you please explain me what is the solution ? Because in this app I am doing in android studio everything is good until if some user press button without entering any numeric number .what I want is to give some kind of toast if button got pressed with an empty text view.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your xml file it seems like that you have miss spelled  your method name there . `android:onClick=guessIt` in button attributes. Because if your app can run and it crushes when you press the button it has to be the `android:onClick` attribute of your button.